# Removing specific "word" from text file

Tags: command-line, updates

I have `.srt` file with subtitles. However, my TV doesn't recognize signs like `<i> </i>` so it is just printed on the screen. I'm looking for a way to delete all the html markup.

Comment: What do you mean by "signs". Can you edit to give an example of a couple of lines of input text and desired output text.

Comment: Original
http://pastebin.com/gXX9viPX

Comment: Post-sed http://pastebin.com/NEUQqhja

Comment: So you want to get rid of <i> and </i> ? Which specific signs or characters you want to remove ?

Comment: If you want to strip out HTML markup specifically, then you might be better off looking at tools that are designed for that e.g. `html2text`

Answer (score 1):

.srt files are .txt files with an .srt extension, so you can open an .srt file in Gedit Text Editor and and easily delete a text string like `<i>` or `</i>` using *Search* -> *Replace* (which opens a new *Replace* window) -> *Replace All*.

You can also replace text strings in the Gnome Subtitiles application, however *Search* -> *Replace* in Gnome Subtitles does not recognize embedded HTML tags. Instead Gnome Subtitles functions like a word processor and allows you to format text in italics without showing its HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

### Via `sed`

but that is **only good enough for *simplistic* HTML.**. For a **better solution via `perl` or `html2text`**, see below.

```
sed -i".$(date +'%s').bak" 's/<[^>]*>//g' your_input_file
```

---

*Explanation*

- `-i".$(date +'%s').bak"`

  edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
- `'s/<[^>]*>//g'`

  - `<` matches the characters `<` literally
  - `[^>]*` match a single character not present in the list below

    - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    - `>` a single character in the list `>` literally (case sensitive)
  - `>` matches the characters `>` literally
  - `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
  - `s` modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters

---

*Example*

- The input file `foo`

  ```
  % cat foo
  2
  00:00:22,000 --> 00:00:28,074
  Advertise your product or brand here
  contact www.OpenSubtitles.org today

  3
  00:00:36,036 --> 00:00:39,096
  <i>When I was a child in India,</i>

  4
  00:00:39,205 --> 00:00:43,005
  <i>growing up in the tiny village
  of Harenmahkeester,</i>

  5
  00:00:45,145 --> 00:00:47,238
  <i>I found a voice-over machine,</i>
  ```
- The command and the new content of the file `foo`

  ```
  % sed -i".$(date +'%s').bak" 's/<[^>]*>//g' foo

  % cat foo
  2
  00:00:22,000 --> 00:00:28,074
  Advertise your product or brand here
  contact www.OpenSubtitles.org today

  3
  00:00:36,036 --> 00:00:39,096
  When I was a child in India,

  4
  00:00:39,205 --> 00:00:43,005
  growing up in the tiny village
  of Harenmahkeester,

  5
  00:00:45,145 --> 00:00:47,238
  I found a voice-over machine,
  ```

---

### Using Perl

1. Install a library

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libfile-slurp-unicode-perl
   ```
2. Create a perl file `removeTags`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use HTML::Parse;
   use HTML::FormatText;
   use File::Slurp;

   my $text = read_file($ARGV[0]);

   $text =~ s/\n/<br>/g;
   $plain_text = HTML::FormatText->new->format(parse_html($text));
   print $plain_text
   ```
3. Use your `srt` file as parameter

   ```
   dos2unix foo.srt; ./removeTags foo.srt | unix2dos > foo_out.srt
   ```

---

### Using `html2text`

```
dos2unix foo.srt; perl -pe 's/\n/<br>/g' foo.srt | html2text | unix2dos > foo_out.srt
```

Comment: @kos You can find any fault. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/<[^>]*>//g|x' file.srt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` replace all instances in each line
4. `x` save and close